# Why is SHLVL initially 2 in Ubuntu 16.10 (but not earlier versions)?

Tags: command-line, scripts, environment-variables, 16.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10. Why does `$SHLVL` *now* start with a value of 2 when I open the Gnome terminal? This was not the case in 16.04.

Comment: This is really annoying; it breaks backward compatibility with environments that try to "save state" when a parent shell exits vs tmp subshells exiting.  Now, no matter how you open a terminal/bash in ubuntu, they all have SHLVL=2. I wonder if there's another way to tell a "parent" vs subshell?

Answer (score 2):

This unfortunate bug was introduced in Ubuntu 16.10.

For a bash work-around, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1707977/comments/3

Answer (score 1):

If you run an application that does not start a shell, but can give you access to the environment variables, you'll see that the environment already contains `SHLVL` with a value of 1. For instance, I installed and ran IDLE3, ran `import os` and checked the value of `os.environ['SHLVL']`, which turned out to be 1.

Now, `SHLVL` is also set and incremented in scripts, so, if I ran a bash script containing `echo $SHLVL` in a terminal, I'd get 3.

However, the consoles/TTYs still have a `SHLVL` of 1, so the culprit must be somewhere in the GUI start process. I don't know what exactly it would be, but my guess is Unity. In GNOME Shell, for example, this does not happen. Somewhere in that startup of Unity, a bash script is probably present.

Answer (score 1):

Following up from my comment in the original question (and, this is not an answer per se, since I can't answer "why", but I can verify the new behavior exists):

This change breaks backward compatibility. Now, no matter how you open a terminal/bash in ubuntu, they all start at `SHLVL=2` Though, I'm not sure if this is a Ubuntu-specific issue, or due to using Unity. If one happens to have logic that does something specific when the parent shell exits (eg saving state), that will now never execute.

(Also, I'm not sure if `~/.bash_logout` is being called at the same time as before, either. Not sure, can't remember. The unpredictability of depending on this behavior is why we use custom logic depending on shell-depth. The only way I can trigger  `~/.bash_logout` it is by explicitly exiting a shell started with `bash -l`; all other Ubuntu bash shells aren't login shells. It could have always been this way.)

In experimenting with ways to try to deduce the true SHLVL, trying to see if there is another way to tell a "parent" vs subshell, this might work (checking for ubuntu is optional, if this is in fact a Unity-specific <strike>bug</strike> feature.)

```
$ echo $SHLVL 
  2

$ my_shlvl() {
    lsb_release -i | grep -qi ubuntu && pstree  -s $$  | grep -o bash | wc -l
  }

$ export -f my_shlvl

$ my_shlvl
  1

$ bash

$ echo $SHLVL 
  3

$ my_shlvl
  2

$ exit

$ my_shlvl
  1
```

This <strike>hack</strike> work-around is very gnu/linux specific (e.g. assumes `pstree`, `lsb_release` exist), but afaik this problem exists only on a subset of linux distros (so far, just ubuntu; but probably others, too, e.g., mint, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really, `man bash` explains, `SHLVL  Incremented by one each time an instance of bash is started.` By the time you look at `$SHLVL` in Gnome terminal, you are two levels deep. If you look at `$SHLVL` in a text (<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F1</kbd>) terminal it will start as `1`.

One can track the progress of `SHLVL`, by adding these lines to one's `.bashrc`:

```
# keep track of the SHLVL values I see.
export SHLVLs="${SHLVLs:='init'}"
SHLVLs="${SHLVLs}:${SHLVL}"
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, an `echo $SHLVL` in a terminal shows 1; in 16.10 it shows 2. The question is why?

Comment: I suggest comparing http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63788/ .

Comment: That link indicates that different shells start with different initial values for $SHLVL. I'm asking why this is different, with Gnome terminal, in Ubuntu 16.10, than it was in 16.04. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: That is not what Gilles' answer says at all.